# Open iOS app from a Safari without "Open in <app>" prompt

Tags: javascript, iphone, schema, mobile-safari, deep-linking

I'm trying to open the app from an HTML page. It's working well, but I need the app to open without asking the permission from the user.

Currently, Safari will ask the user that "Open this page in myapp". I don't want this message box.

How I can remove this message from Safari? I'm using an URI scheme to open the app. It looks something like `myApp://domain`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't avoid the dialog you mentioned while using Custom URL schemes. This is iOS feature.

Instead you can use Universal Links to open your iOS App without additional dialog. You need to have control over iOS App to make this happens.

To simplify Universal Links setup, you can use one of the companies that can setup most of it for you. I am working in Firebase/Google https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ . Other answer mentioned company that will do this for you as well.

Comment: Danger! Universal Links are basically broken, in that iOS can and will open the URL in the browser instead of the app whenever it feels like it. We had to drop UL for payment flow and use old-fashioned custom URL scheme for this reason. Do not rely on Universal Links!

Answer (score 0):

Try [branch.io](https://docs.branch.io)? It works with Android and iOS.